# In Trifacta or Google Cloud Dataprep, i'm trying to flag rows with non alpha numeric (�). What formula do I use?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

In Trifacta or Google Cloud Dataprep, i'm trying to flag rows with non alpha numeric (�). What formula do I use? 
tried this formula but doesn't work

```
Replace Matches of `�` from EMPLOYEE_FIRST with NOT VALID
```

Comment: Please be more specific regarding did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"?

The following step works for me in Dataprep. You can paste it directly into the New Step wizard:

```
replacepatterns col: EMPLOYEE_FIRST with: 'NOT VALID' on: `�` global: true
```

If that does not work for you, can you please post a screenshot of what happens after adding (or trying to add) this step?

Comment: no changes after i tried this step.  same values with  "�"  appeared on the previewed column. I want to flag those rows in EMPLOYEE_FIRST column with  "�" . I'm also trying to look for a boolean formula to tag it as true if  "�"  exist

Comment: Alright, well I just replicated my initial result on free Wrangler as well. I am using a very trivial CSV dataset. What is the type of your input dataset? How is it encoded? Did you modify encoding during import?

Comment: it's a simple txt file from third party and i'm trying to transform it using cloud dataprep. the actual value from .txt file is "Ñ". when dataset is imported to dataprep, the value becomes "�"

Comment: I made a text file that only contained instances of Ñ. It came up just fine in Dataprep. However, when I re-imported the file and changed the encoding to US-ASCII, it came up as all � characters.That is why I asked about the encoding, and mentioned changing the encoding during import (see Edit Settings after you specify the file to import). Dataprep imports using UTF-8 by default, but something is interfering. Perhaps you can work around this by playing with the encoding during import.

Comment: I should add: if no headway then consider filing a support ticket with Trifacta (support@trifacta.com). Include a link to this thread for context, as well as the edition of Dataprep (click Settings => About) and if possible your sample dataset.

Comment: I re-uploaded the dataset and set the encoding to US-ASCII. It worked! Thanks for your help!